# Problem in retrieving datetime parameter from url

Tags: php, curl

iam passing some parameters in url to a page through curl, but to my surprise, iam not able to retrieve all of the parameters.

This is an example of my url:

**http://localhost/a.php?include=true&F1=2011-01-23 12:20:00&F2=2011-01-25 01:00:00**

But in my "a.php" page, when i printed:

> $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]

iam getting it like this:   **a.php?include=true&F1=2011-01-23**

iam not getting full F1 parameter, and F2 parameter is not coming at all. I hope it is the problem with the space in the datetime parameters. If so, how to accomplish this?

Note that i cant change the datetime value as part of url, like i cant use timestamp instead of that.

Comment: added sample code... not getting F2 parameter in the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propobly it space problem. In url's space is encoded as '+'. Can you use urlencode in your curl script like this:

```
 $url = "http://localhost/a.php?include=true&F1=".urlencode("2011-01-23 12:20:00")."&F2=".urlencode("2011-01-25 01:00:00");
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked perfectly. Just a small change... i used the urlencode function only once for encoding all my parameters, like: 

$url = "http://localhost/a.php?include=true".urlencode('F1=2011-01-23 12:20:00&F2=2011-01-25 01:00:00'); And i used url_decode in a.php for getting the url correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It might worth to try to `urlencode` the `$_GET` properly

```
$arr = 
array
(
  'include'=>'true', 
  'F1'=>'2011-01-23 12:20:00', 
  'F2'=>'2011-01-25 01:00:00'
);
$url = 'http://localhost/a.php?'.http_build_query($arr);
```